# Novel ID: Book with cloning and an evil clown alien

Tags: story-identification, novel, clones

I'm looking for a science fiction book. There is a station orbiting earth and a message showing aliens being attacked by other aliens. A warning to humanity. I recall the evil aliens looking like a clown. There is cloning later in the book. People are interrogated and killed. Then the next clone is brought in.

Comment: Send in the clones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am reminded of Pohl's [Eschaton Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_End_of_Time_(novel))

In this series of novels, aliens occupy a human space station in Earth orbit, and have teleportation technology allowing humans and others to be duplicated (thus the clones you remember).  In addition, the aliens on the space station send warning messages to Earth about the dangers of a different faction of aliens. Some of the aliens look silly - humans call them "Dopeys," "Docs" or "Scarecrows," which may correspond to the "clown" memory you have.

This [review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9780312866181) of the third book in the series mentions the interrogation of duplicates:

> At the start of the novel, Dannerman is cloned by a group of alien
> Horch and imprisoned so they can interrogate him about life on our
> planet.